# Telegram-bot on python. "Error code: 400...... Wrong string length" Новичок, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать так что бы я отправлял боту  несколько фото, он сохранял их File_id в txt документ после чего мог скинуть эти фото(все сразу) в переписку с помощью этих же File_id.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Primer\Prod13.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.writelines(file_info.file_id)
    f.writelines('\n')
 bot.reply_to(message, "Фото добавлено")
```

Это первая часть, где бот дожен сохранять File_id фотки.

```
n =2
 z = 0
 with open(r"C:\Users\Primer\Prod13.txt", 'r') as f:
    for i in range(n):
        photoidlist = f.readlines()
        photoid = photoidlist[z]
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, photoidlist[z])
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, photoid)
        z += 1
```

Вот вторая часть.
Я ещё сделал так что он отправляет File_id каждой фотки в переписку(чат) но на первом сообщении он и останавливается(не скинув фото). Насколько я понимаю в ошибке пишет что File_id неправильный, но если скинуть фото с тем File_id что бот отправил в чат он спокойно отправляет фотку.
Помогите пожалуйста я новичок и в питоне и в телеграм ботах, очень надо, бкдк очень благодарен. Зарание спасибо!!!!!

Comment: 1: Необходимо вынести photoidlist = f.readlines() за пределы цикла for, т.к. при каждой итерации он считывает, зачем не понятно.
2: после объявления photoidlist, добавьте 
    photoIdList = [line.rstrip() for line in photoIdList]
это удалит все знаки переноса строк, т.к. при readlines() этот знак тоже считывается

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov Спасибо вам большое, работает)

Comment: я  бы порекомендовал почитать стайлгайды. Т.к. ваш код сложночитаем. Именование переменных, отступы. В Python 2е особенно важно

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov   ок, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Необходимо вынести

```
photoidlist = f.readlines()
```

за пределы цикла for, т.к. при каждой итерации он считывает, зачем не понятно.
2: после объявления photoidlist, добавьте

```
photoIdList = [line.rstrip() for line in photoIdList]
```

это удалит все знаки переноса строк, т.к. при readlines() этот знак тоже считывается